# Show menu on button click in android

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, onclick

I just want the normal menu which gets displayed on clicking the settings button in android phone instead with Virtual Button Click. I tried `openOptionsMenu();` but it didn't help. I hope you understand the problem here: I want for example default "setting" option displayed which we see when I click on button in actionbar but this time I have action bar hidden so I have a button which I want to display the menu on Clicking that button.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to override the Menu button programmatically

Comment: Its already done so. If I understand @Override is already used before onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad So I want menu to be displayed if I click on virtual button. That's all. I will vote u up coz this was new but can you tell me solution for that as well.

Comment: For this you can make a custom View in your layout xml and make Visibility="gone"

And when you click on the button make visibility Visible

Answer (score 0):

You can set its property in `xml` file to **invisible** or **gone** & in the `.java` file set it to **visible** see code below:

**Note:** In my case I'm using Buttons you can use according to your own

.java file:

```
Button next,btn;

public void newBtnL(View view){
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ListenBtn);
     btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newBtn);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

.xml file:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/ListenBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_stop_service"
        android:onClick="newBtnL"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ListenBtn"
        android:text="that"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```